# Can't see table contents, etc. for SQL Server Compact Edition tables

Tags: sql-server-ce

I received an application that has a `.sdf` associated with it. I can connect to the `.sdf` with Management Studio - and I can see the tables along with the column headers for the table I'm interested in viewing.

However, there's no option to display the table data. Is there a way for me to export the table to Excel or to otherwise view it?

Comment: Which version of SQL CE and Management Studio are you using?

Comment: 64 bit version, SQL CE v = 3.5 , Studio = SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open the .sdf file using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) or you could use this [nice command line tool](http://sqlcecmd.codeplex.com/) for SQL CE.

There are also other useful add-ons and standalone tools on CodePlex. Check out [exportsqlce.codeplex.com](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/) and [sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/)